# Increase spacing in closing of cover letter in moderncv

Tags: spacing, moderncv

Using the `moderncv` package, how do I increase the spacing between the closing and the name after the closing i.e. increasing the space between "Yours faithfully" and "John Doe" in this picture

[image: picture]

This is the default `template.tex` available at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples.

Comment: An answer to your question was submitted some time ago, please consider marking the answer as  ‘Accepted’ (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)) or explain why the answer given did not answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add vertical space in your name:

```
\firstname{\vspace{20pt}John}
\familyname{Doe}
```

Which will only change the spacing between *Your's Faithfully* and *John Doe*.

A different solution would be to change the spacing using the `setspace` package (add `\usepackage{setspace}` in your preamble). Change the spacing before adding the closing, for example:

```
\doublespacing
\makeletterclosing
```

or

```
\setstretch{2}
\makeletterclosing
```

This will, however, also change the space between *John Doe* and *Attached: curriculum vitæ*

Answer (score 5):

The `\makeletterclosing` macro puts a vertical space of 3em between closing and name. In the following example I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to change this space to 4em.

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{3em}{4em}{}{}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]